# Why is 'publishing' function not being found in my custom gradle.kts file within buildSrc directory?

Tags: gradle, maven-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, maven-publish

I have a custom gradle.kts script I am building that will do our maven publishing for all of our various modules to our sonatype repository, but encountering a strange error. Here are the contents of my `maven-deploy.gradle.kts` file:

```kotlin
plugins {
    `maven-publish`
    signing
}

publishing {
  //expression 'publishing' cannot be invoked as a function.
  //The function invoke() is not found
}
```

I can run tasks and whatnot within the `maven-deploy.gradle.kts` file fine, but trying to use the `publishing` function from the gradle documentation is proving to be impossible. Any ideas? I'm using gradle version 4.10.3 (I need Android support). The `maven-deploy.gradle.kts` file is in `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin` and is being added by `id("maven-deploy")` in my main project's `build.gradle.kts` file.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This happens because Gradle only imports the generated type-safe accessors for Gradle Kotlin DSL into the main build script, but not into *script plugins*:

> Only the main project build scripts have type-safe model accessors. Initialization scripts, settings scripts, script plugins (precompiled or otherwise) do not. These limitations will be removed in a future Gradle release.

See [Understanding when type-safe model accessors are available](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#kotdsl:accessor_applicability)

In the script you mentioned, you can access the publishing extension dynamically, for example, using `configure<PublishingExtension> { ... }`:

```kotlin
import org.gradle.api.publish.PublishingExtension

plugins {
    `maven-publish`
    signing
}

configure<PublishingExtension> { 
    // ...
}
```

This is described here: [Project extensions and conventions](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#project_extensions_and_conventions)

UPD: Gradle 5.3 RC1 seems to add a possibility to use the generated extensions in script plugins.

Comment: Works great! Thank you! :-) And thank you for the documentation links as well (I really needed those)

Comment: A small step but it's missing from every tutorial, even googles documentation. thanks.